# Remember login using laravel auth login failed only on mobile-Safari

Tags: laravel, session, mobile-safari, laravel-10

I made a website support google login, and when success callback, using Auth::loginUsingId(user_id,true), so the user can login again even browser close, and the whole login process works fine on chrome but failed on mobile Safari.

I tried regular login request, using Auth:attempt([credentials],true), and user can login again even browser close on mobile Safari

```
if ($google_user) {
    $app_user = $google_user->appUser;
    if ($app_user) {
        Auth::loginUsingId($app_user->id, true);
        return redirect('/');
    } 
}
```

---

```
if (Auth::attempt($this->only('email', 'password'), true)) {
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: It depends on your browser's configuration. It's not related to your browser(chrome, safari or etc). If your browser accepts cookies then remember me will work. It's seem that cookie saving disabled in your safari.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I remote debug safari, I found that there will same name cookies for session in similar domain, example.com and [www].example.com.

Then I went to google clould console, using example.com for url and it's works.